# Online tool for crawling a website and retriving all meta information for every page

Tags: seo, web-crawler, meta-tags

Does anyone know of a free online tool that can crawl any given website and return just the Meta Keywords and Meta Description information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to Linux/Unix:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
wget -r SITE_ADDRESS
```

Then, for keywords:

```
egrep -r -h 'meta[^>]+name="keywords' * | sed 's/^.*content="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/g'
```

and for descriptions:

```
egrep -r -h 'meta[^>]+name="description' * | sed 's/^.*content="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/g'
```

If you want all the unique keywords, try:

```
egrep -r -h 'meta[^>]+name="keywords' * | sed 's/^.*content="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/g' | sed 's/\s*,\s*/\n/g' | sort | uniq
```

I'm sure there's a one-liner or program out there that does this exact thing, and there are definitely easier answers.

Answer (score 1):

To retrive all meta information try this tool [Meta Tags Analyzer](http://www.seotoolsfree.in/meta-tags-analyzer/)